# Constant for 'barebones' update of Wordpress

Tags: updates, wp-config, constants

I feel slightly stupid asking this, but I could have *sworn* I stumbled across a constant that could be added to `wp-config.php` so that, when you update your Wordpress installation, it **only** updates Wordpress and doesn't download additional things like the default theme.

However, I now can't find it for the life of me. I've searched a dozen different terms and checked the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php), but can't find any references to it anywhere. Did I dream it?

Comment: Does the built in updater not already do this by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the old days when WordPress updated you got the whole shebang and deleting Akismet after every time was deadly boring.

Things had slightly improved since then (partially driven by minimizing traffic it takes to serve update to everyone), but process also got more complicated.

Now there are multiple versions of update archive that core might receive and apply. They are (at least):

- partial (only differences, I *think* this ignores content folder)
- new bundled (only includes *new* things in content folder, such as annual theme)
- no content
- full

Now on most updates you are likely getting partial or new bundled. It means effectively that once you remove bundled plugin/theme it won't reappear. However *new* one will, for example WordPress 4.1 added Twenty Fifteen to my install, but not older themes I had previously removed.

So the *old* things stay removed already. To also disable *new* things there is a `CORE_UPGRADE_SKIP_NEW_BUNDLED` constant, which is what you might be thinking about.

Comment: THANKYOU! As soon as I saw the name of it, I knew this is what I'd seen before. Annoying that there's no reference to it anywhere on the Codex (that I can find, at least).